# Data binding property in dev express grid designer not found

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have this class as you can see :

```
   public class Document
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Number { set; get; }
        public string Class { set; get; }
        public string Discipline { set; get; }
        public string Unit { set; get; }
        public DateTime SubmitDateTime { set; get; }


    }
```

It has a repository to get data from database ,in my form in UI in put a `gridviewDevExpress` so i pass my data using my repository to `dev express gridview`

```
 private void frmDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridControlDocument.DataSource = _documentRepository.Get().ToList();
        }
```

I want to bind my class to grid view,so i define my columns in gridview as  you can see :

[image]

I want to bind my data base columns to grid view columns .I don't know where is the property ?

The result of my running is :

I have a record in database

[image]

Comment: Have you specified the [GridColumn.FieldName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FieldNametopic) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property on DevExpress `gridview` for columns that is called `FieldName`. So you can add database column name to `FieldName`.

Answer (score 0):

You should either to create all the specific columns with the correctly assigned  [GridColumn.FieldName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FieldNametopic) properties or do not create columns at all (in this case the GridControl will automatically populate columns itself).
For details, I suggest you use the following tutorial which describes the XtraGrid's design-time data binding specifics: [Create and Manage Columns at Design Time](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114681).

Please, also read the following article that describes the data binding aspects related to columns: [Creating Columns and Binding Them to Data Fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument639)

Moreover, you can use the [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument18159) that allows you to choose the specific binding mode (direct, server-side, parallel or asynchronous)  for various data sources (ADO, EF, SQL, Excel, WCF, XML, IEnumerable/IList and etc).